# Next.js :Uncaught (in promise) Error: The provided `href` (/confirmation/[token]) value is missing query values (token) to be interpolated properly

Tags: next.js, token, string-interpolation, next-router

Not sure how to resolve this error, as the docs mention a Link tag:

> Why This Error Occurred
>
> Somewhere you are utilizing the next/link component, Router#push, or
> Router#replace with href interpolation to build dynamic routes but did
> not provide all of the needed dynamic route params to properly
> interpolate the href.
>
> Note: this error will only show when the next/link component is
> clicked not when only rendered.

**Invalid href interpolation**

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function BlogLink() {
  return (
    <Link
      href={{
        pathname: '/blog/[post]/[comment]',
        query: { post: 'post-1' },
      }}
    >
      <a>Invalid link</a>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

In my case I am generating an email with a link in it:

> Please verify your account by clicking the following link:
> http://localhost:8016/confirmation/ef2ad8e7dc5e60a8a0c6a640f26f5dcd

so in my pages directory if have:

[image]

And my page is importing a component which renders the confirmation page:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import axios from 'axios';
import Message from '../../components/Message/index';

export default function isConfirmation(
  dispatch,
  error,
  setError,
  setResponseMessage = () => { },
  responseMessage,
  token
) {

  const [showApi, setShowApi] = useState(true);
  const router = useRouter();


  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true

    if (!router.isReady) return;

    console.log("token 27 in CONFIRMATION ", token);
    axios
      .get(`/api/confirmation/${token}`)
      .then(response => {

        console.log("response ", response);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          isSubscribed ? setResponseMessage(response.data.msg) : null;
        }

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 404) {
          dispatch({ type: 'resetUserAccountIsVerified' })

          setError(true);
          isSubscribed ? setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg) : null;

        }

        if (error.response.status === 400) {
          dispatch({ type: 'userAccountIsVerified' })

          setError(true);
          isSubscribed ? setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg) : null;

        }
      });

    return () => {
      isSubscribed = false;
      setShowApi(prev => !prev);
    };
  }, [router.query.token]);



  if (error) {
    return showApi && <Message state="Error" content={responseMessage} />
  }
  if (error === false) {
    return showApi && <Message state="Success" header={responseMessage} />
  }
}
```

The token has a value from my `console.log` above and the request to my `/api/confirmation/:token` works (e.g. I get a response) it's just the page doesn't render right and I get that error.

Please help!

Comment: Do you have a `Link` to `/confirmation/[token]` anywhere in your code? That's probably where the error is coming from.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks! I did a quick search  and don’t see that in my code I.e a Link tag with that path…

Comment: And the same for any potential `router.push`? You don't have `/confirmation/[token]` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Weird I did a search  for that too and nada. https://github.com/antonioOrtiz/hillfinder/search?q=router.push&type=